# How to make a child inherit from two parent class?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance

I know it's impossible in PHP, but in Laravel, the default User model inherits from Authenticatable, but I also need it to inherit from a parent class that I created.

Is there a work around to this?

Comment: only Multilevel inheritance supported in php not multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is not a programming language, it is written in PHP, so as you said:

> it's impossible in PHP

You should make your parent class inherit from Authenticatable and inherit from the parent class. Otherwise, use traits.

Comment: Then as I said, create traits instead.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to make the default User model of Laravel inherits from their own parent class, here's how I did it:

```
use App\Models\Classes\BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class User extends BaseModel implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait, Notifiable;
```